# How to apply external stylesheet to iframe child component in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am rendering a component inside an iframe and unable to apply CSS via external stylesheet.Applied head prop in link tag
This is a code snippet to link to external stylesheet.

```
import React from "react";
import classNames from "classnames";
import Frame from "./Frame";
import "./styles.css";

class Hello extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      show: false
    };
  }

  toggleState = () => {
    console.log("before clicked", this.state.show);
    this.setState({ show: !this.state.show });
  };
  
  render() {
    var classes = classNames({
      "": !this.state.show,
      "u-isHidden": this.state.show
    });

    return (
      <Frame head={
          <link
            type="text/css"
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="./styles.css"
          />}>
        <div onClick={this.toggleState}>
          VAL: {this.state.show.toString()}
          <div className={this.state.show ? "": 'u-isHidden'}>
            this.state.show is true and now I'm visible
          </div>
          Hello {this.props.name}
        </div>
      </Frame>
    );
  }
}

export default Hello;
```

CSS

```
*{
  color: red;
  font-size: x-large;
}

.u-isHidden {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

The whole code can be seen in https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-sea-xzmz6

Comment: I did see whole page with background red, you are mentioning it is not applied?

Comment: @GokulnathP please check it now!